# How to use pd.to_datetime() for a column with year-month-day hour:min:sec data?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a column with some date-time data in a pandas data frame.

The format of the date-time data is `'2016-10-04 07:59:42'`.

I want to convert the date-time data to datetime data type.

I've tried using the below code, but I get a `ValueError`.

Thanks for any help!

```
# Library 
import pandas as pd 

# Data 
data = [['tom', '2016-10-04 07:59:42'], ['nick', '2016-10-04 07:59:42'], ['juli', '2016-10-04 07:59:42']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Finished']) 

# Format column 
df['Finished'] = pd.to_datetime([f'{y}-{m}-{d}{hr}{mi}{se}' for y, m, d, hr, mi, se in df.Finished])
```

Comment: change to, ``pd.to_datetime(df.Finished, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")``

Comment: If the data comes from a csv then pandas will parse it for you https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#datetime-handling

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
df.Finished = pd.to_datetime(df.Finished, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```